# Track configuration file in GitHub

Tags: git

I have a GitHub repository which looks like this

```
README.md
LICENSE
dummydf
test_dummydf
.gitignore
```

Where `dummydf` is my actual module. This module uses a config file called `config_dummydf.yml` which is not yet in the remote repository, but only in my local one.

I would like to have my config file tracked in my repository, just like the other files. However, I've read that it is bad practice to have config files (files that are not source code in general) in a repository. That they should be always added to `.gitignore` file.

What are the best practices for config files?

Comment: If only you are using the repository and you don't have any secret keys in the configuration file (especially important if the repository is public) then you can have the configuration file in the repository.

Comment: @md2perpe thanks a lot. Do I need to create a new folder create config/ for it?

Comment: No. Where you want to place the config file is up to you.

Comment: "Best practices" questions are not suited to stackoverflow (which is about solving one particular technical issue at a time, not about overall planning); this probably belongs on softwareengineering or some other such site. That said: a config file that *users will change* should not be committed; a config file that *users will not touch*, that merely configures the software as part of its normal operation because that's easier than having it hard-coded into the software itself, should be committed like any other source code.

Comment: For user-oriented config files, as the Git FAQ says, you should include an *example or template* file that will show up in each checkout, but that is not used by the software. I tend to modify this into *defaults file* (that *is* used but is overridden by user's config). Note: this isn't specific to Python *or* GitHub (and not really even specific to Git, but it needs some tag) so I snipped those two tags.

Comment: @torek thanks a lot for your input. Is the config file to be put in the dummydf folder? Or would it be better to place it separately?

Comment: That's up to you - where do you want to find it? How does your software operate? Do you install the software and then look for the config file in `/etc` or `/usr/local/etc`, or do you run out of `/home/users/<username>/Library/StartupFiles/myapp.app/`? etc.

Comment: @torek I'm a newbie here looking for best practices. My software consists of a main script which reads the config file (that contains parameters to avoid hardcoding).